# IntelliJ IDEA - caret behavior

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to figure out one thing in IntelliJ IDEA 10:

[image]

1. current caret position
2. where caret moves after pressing DOWN arrow
3. where I want caret to be

Is such setting possible?

Comment: I hate this feature, and don't know anyone liking it. I have created an issue there : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126901 Don't hesitate to vote!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`File` | `Settings` (or `Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | **Allow placement of caret after end of line**:

[image: Settings | Editor | Allow placement of caret after end of line]

Comment: nope, didn't work for me. Also problem is when I just randomly click in whitespace far beyond the end of line, caret is not set to last relevant position, but where I clicked. If it's not clear from my explanation, I can also provide screenshot.

Comment: Please double check, it's exactly the option controlling the behavior you describe. It muse be DISABLED to get what you want, make sure to press OK or Apply after making the change. Reopen the dialog and verify the it's still DISABLED.

Comment: Silly me, I thought I should enable it. Thank you very much!

Comment: For anybody struggling with this, be sure to disable the Column Selection Mode – I just accidentally had it on and caret placement settings had 0 effect.

Answer (score 29):

Please note that this effect can also occur if you activate *Column Selection Mode* under:
<kbd>Edit -> Column Selection Mode</kbd>
which allows you to make square selections.

Comment: This was my issue as well, don't forget to go and remove the keybinding if this happens to you sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + Alt + Insert to disable the column selection mode.

[image: column mode]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Caret behaviour as below shown in the screenshot:

[image]