# RubyMine - Turning off ability to click in middle of "empty" lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I've recently begun learning Ruby and I'm really enjoying it so far. The IDE I've chosen to use is RubyMine (as it's similar to PhpStorm). There is however one feature which annoys me greatly and I cannot find the configuration for.

**What I want to get rid of is:**
When coding I am able to click in the middle of a line (where I haven't placed whitespace), and the cursor will jump there and allow me to type there (as if I had placed indented the code a long way before beginning to write).

```
                                  The result might look something like this.
```

If I clicked in the middle of the line and began typing.

Does anyone know how to turn this feature off?

If my description is too vague, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA - caret behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493697/intellij-idea-caret-behavior)

Comment: @CrazyCoder, how is a question about RubyMine a duplicate of a question about IntelliJ? I had this problem too, was I supposed to know to google for IntelliJ instead?

Comment: @Victor, RubyMine is based on IntelliJ IDEA platform, so it has the same behavior (as well as PyCharm, WebStorm, PhpStorm).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, that's absolutely true, but still not very useful for someone who has this problem.  I found this answer right away, I don't know how long would it have taken me to find the IntelliJ IDEA one.

Comment: @Victor, imagine that this question was closed as a duplicate, in this case you would still be able to find it on Google or directly here using the same keywords, but it would redirect you to the same answer as provided by Dennis below. In case the option location would change in the future, only one answer can be corrected. Now it would require fixing all the duplicate answers.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, thanks for the explanation. If it was a duplicate answer, that would be true.  Imagine that, being a different product, Rubymine does things differently.  Then you have to reopen all the duplicates.  This is not a class you have to abstract away, this is stackoverflow's user interface.  You know DRY? Doesn't necessarily apply to user interface.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to disable Settings | Editor | Virtual Space | Enable placement of caret after end of line

Comment: Thank you! I, too, was wondering about disabling this feature.

Comment: This setting is is in Preferences -> Editor -> Allow placement of caret after end of line is

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the most annoying default feature in an IDE I've ever come across.

Comment: Why in the world would this ever be added as a default setting?? Thank you for the answer to this.

Answer (score 6):

If you find that `Allow placement of caret after end of line` is already unchecked, try *checking* the box then exit and restart the IDE. Go back into settings and un-check again.  This was the only way I could get it to work on a fresh install of PhpStorm v3.0.3 - no amount of check/uncheck would disable the behavior without this restart sequence.

Answer (score 2):

In Rubymine 4.5 I needed to restart in order to get rid off the carets

Answer (score 2):

In RubyMine 5.4, 
File > Settings > IDE Settings section > Editor > Virtual space "section" >
[*] Allow placement of caret after end of line

Remove the check from the checkbox.

It does not require restarting.

Answer (score 1):

In RubyMine 7.1 File > Preferences > Editor > General, Virtual Space section