# Phpstorm - I can click on white space even after a line has finished, i don't want to be able to

Tags: whitespace, phpstorm

apologies as I realise this shouldn't be in stackoverflow and one of his sisters spin off's.

But its driving me insane, but going to the end of a line when I click on the white space of a line.

I have a fresh install on a different machine and it doesn't do this, so I know its my version.

I have clicked the small 'reset' in settings with no luck.

Comment: have you tried to reinstall it?

Comment: have you seen this? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27xzGoXSReA

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA - caret behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493697/intellij-idea-caret-behavior)

Comment: crazycoder, i'll give that a whirl when i get back to my machine at home. Seems odd that this would be 'default' behaviour though.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You likely have either "Column Selection Mode" or "Allow placement of caret after end of line" enabled.

To turn off Column Selection Mode, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#column_selection.

To turn off caret after EOL placement, deselect the preference in Settings > Editor > Virtual Space.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, had i know what a cravat was then i would have been able to search for this :p

Comment: By default, you can turn it of with the maj+alt+inser shortcut. And if i may add a good trick which almost all editors like Notepad++ or phpstorm understand : hold Alt key when you select, and it does a selection in column mode.

Comment: Weirdly enough this setting can get activated without it showing in the settings. Turning it on and off as with many things fixes it ;)