# Annoying text space around cursor in PhpStorm

Tags: macos, cursor, phpstorm

Anybody have any idea how to fix this before I go insane?

[image: phpstorm]

Comment: see below link: [click the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523801/phpstorm-i-can-click-on-white-space-even-after-a-line-has-finished-i-dont-wa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the color scheme and that fixed it  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: And how, please, would I do that?

Comment: In the main Preferences window, under Appearance & Behavior > Appearance. Changing the theme there seemed to fix it for me

Comment: I did: Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Reset

Works perfectly, thank you kilrizzy!

Answer (score 0):

That is a font ligature to make sure letters don't overlap.

You can either change your font or change the ligature:
Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font -> Enable Font Ligatures