# PHPStorm 4 cursor

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

I don't know if anyone has tried the all-new [PHPStorm 4](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/index.html), but I've got a problem with this new version that I didn't have with the previous major version (PHPStorm 3).

Basically, when I click anywhere in the blank space of my code view, the cursor is set at this position, instead of going at the first char available on the line where I clicked:

[image: PHPStorm cursor example]

I first thought this was an intended choice from the PHPStorm team, but my co-worker installed this software on his Mac (I'm on Windows), and for him the cursor does go to the beginning of the line.

This is pretty annoying, do you have a pointer to a configuration option for this?

Comment: I have not such problem on my windows machine. Maybe it changes in settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA - caret behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493697/intellij-idea-caret-behavior)

Comment: @CrazyCoder: it is, although I wouldn't have been able to find this question! Upvoted your answer, anyway ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the settings go to `IDE Settings -> Editor -> Allow placement of caret after end of line` and untick the option.

[image]

Comment: Saved my life. Almost through my machine out the window because of this problem.