# How do I turn off the unlimited whitespace in IntelliJ 12?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IntelliJ IDEA - caret behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493697/intellij-idea-caret-behavior)

Previous versions had 'Allow placement of caret after end of line' in Settings -> Editor -> Virtual Space, but I can't seem to find it in the new version (12).

Edit: it is in the same place... Settings on a Mac is in Command+, as opposed to File -> Settings (on a PC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDEA 12 has exactly the same setting:

[image: caret]