# Move text cursor to previous string when I am at the left corner of current string

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible in IntelliJ IDEA to move cursor to previous string when it is at the left corner of current string and I am pushing on left arrow keyboard key.

Let me explain:

1) **Text cursor at the left corner of line 4**

[image: First state]

2) **I am pushing on left arrow keyboard key**

[image: Second state]

3) **All I want to get - move text cursor to end of previous (3) line**

[image: Third state]

*But IDEA not moving text cursor from previous line, it just stays there.*

Help me please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA - caret behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493697/intellij-idea-caret-behavior)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because by default IntelliJ allows placing the caret after the end of line. When you press your <kbd>←</kbd> key, it does not move as it would have to go to the infinite right side of your file, which is not very convenient (at least that's how I understand it :p).

Go to `Settings > Editor` and uncheck `Allow placement of caret after end of line`, this will solve your problem.