# How to stop end of line in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying WebStorm editor (currently use vim).

And I noticed I cannot tell where the end of the line is, because you can literally move your cursor beyond the end of the line in the code editor.

I find this very frustrating. I use to be able to know for certain where the end of the line was in vi.

Is there a way to force the cursor to go to next line when I reach the end of a line and move to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WebStorm 11**

By default, the caret is not allowed after the end of the line.

If this check box was already checked, it can be unchecked in 2 different ways:

1. **File > Settings... > Editor > General** > uncheck "**Allow placement of caret after end of line**" (in the Virtual Space section)

   [image]
   [image]
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or go to **Help > Find Action...**:

   [image]

   Type "Allow placement", choose the "Virtual Space: Allow placement of caret after..." line and click on the switch button to have **OFF** instead of ON. If you cannot see the whole description, you can put the mouse over the line.

   [image]

Answer (score 18):

As WebStorm is based on the IntelliJ IDEA platform, [this answer is also valid for WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493742/104891).

`File` | `Settings` (or `Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | **Allow placement of caret after end of line**.